# php proc_open how to detect that the command is completed / proc_open() expects at least 3 parameters

Tags: php, ffmpeg, proc-open

Here is my code

```
$descriptorspec = array( 0 => array("pipe", "r") );
$call_mp4 = "ffmpeg command ...... ";
$openMp4 = proc_open($call_mp4, $descriptorspec , $pipe);
$isMp4stillcompressing  = proc_get_status( $openMp4 );
while ( $isMp4stillcompressing['running'] ) {
    echo '• ';
}
```

The "bug" I have is that it goes without end ;(

Why is that ?

My main goal is to output a dot or other info while being converted

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this order, the variable `$isMp4stillcompressing` will be set once outside the while loop, and remain true forever inside the loop. It needs to be checked each time the loop runs:

```
$isMp4stillcompressing  = proc_get_status( $openMp4 );

while ( $isMp4stillcompressing['running'] ) {
    echo '• ';
    $isMp4stillcompressing  = proc_get_status( $openMp4 );
}
```